# How to select the last inserted text in vim

Tags: vim

How to select the last inserted text in vim? For example I want to be able to type a text, exit the insert mode, select what I have just inserted, and change it to uppercase.

Note: I do not consider Caps Lock a solution here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use

```
v`[
```

to select the last insert if you are still at the correct cursor position.

```
`[
```

jumps to the beginning of your last insert,

```
`]
```

jumps to the end of the last insert respectively. So to be independent of your current cursor position, you'd type

```
`[v`]~
```

to toggle the capitalization of your last insert.

Comment: An alternative to `v ~` is `gU` and `gu` to capitalize/lowercase the next move.

Comment: this only selects the last word. if the last insert has multiple word it doesn't select all of them.